# Функция с переменным числом аргументов

Tags: python

Дана функция:

```
def abc(first, *others):
```

**ВВОД:**

слово1 слово2 слово3 слово4 слово5

**ВЫВОД:**

теперь в **first** хранится слово1, а в **others** хранится список с остальными словами

Вопрос: как правильно вызвать функцию, чтобы вводить просто числа и на выходе иметь переменную first с первым именем и соответственно others со своими переменными
[слово1] слово2 слово3 слово4 слово5

Comment: а вызвать функцию так `print(abc(0, 0))` не пробовали?

Comment: Это единственный способ, чтоб достичь предполагаемой цели? Может еще варианты?

Comment: у вас все правильно работает: `print(abc("x", "y", 123, 456, 789))`

Comment: У вас какая-то мешанина. Кроме того, я не понимаю, зачем вам в функции аргумент `rest`, вы его не используете. Нет ли ошибки, может `rest` и `res` по задумке это одна переменная, а не две разные?

Comment: спасибо, подправил. там только res. Функция ничего не делает, просто выводит. Хочу понять алгоритм, как мне при вводе не вызывать функцию, а сразу писать числа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, вот обычная распаковка аргументов:

```
x, y, *res = input().split()
# вводится 1 2 3 4 5, и затем переменная res должна превратиться в [3, 4, 5]
print(res)
```

Ввод:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Вывод:

```
['3', '4', '5']
```

А вот распаковка при вызове функции:

```
def abc(x, y, *res):
    print(res)

abc(*input().split())
```

Ввод:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Вывод:

```
('3', '4', '5')
```

Comment: Верно. Но как это сделать в функции?

Comment: @Евгений Добавил. Это оно или опять не совсем?

Comment: Изменил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста. А почему на выходе кортеж?

Comment: @Евгений Ну, это в языке такие правила, он так присваивает аргументы в кортеж. Если хотите, кортеж легко превращается в список через `list(res)`

Comment: Понял, спасибо!